# How to increase font size in Vim editor?

Tags: fonts, vim

I write C programs in Vim; the font size in it is very small.

Is there any option to increase the font size in Vim?

Comment: You could try zooming in on your terminal with <Ctrl-Shift-+>

Comment: are you using vim or gvim?

Comment: It's got something to do with `:set guifont=`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According with http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font:

> Console Vim uses whatever font your console/terminal is using. [...]
>
> When running inside a terminal, Vim can, at most, change the colours (within the limits of the colours supported by the terminal: sometimes bold and unbold black and white, often 8 colours plus bold/unbold foreground only [or seen another way, 8 background and 16 foreground]; on X11 some terminals support up to 256 background and foreground colours; "changing colours" usually also includes the use of reverse-video), and, if the terminal supports them (not all terminals do, and even those which do may support it only with certain fonts), use bold, underline and/or italic.

That being said, if you want to change the font size in Vim editor, you have to change the font size of your terminal. To do this in gnome-terminal go to **Edit** → **Profile Preferences**:

[image: Profile Preferences]

Moreover, you can save these preferences in a new terminal profile and when you are start using Vim, use that profile.

Answer (score 27):

This may not be an ideal solution but it works for me.

Just zoom in on your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

Zoom out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: the +/- on the numpad, don't seem to work

Comment: this works for me.

Answer (score 8):

As @Costa said in the comment, you can

1. run `:set guifont` to get the current font
2. for me, that is `Hack 10`
3. then set the font with a larger size `:set guifont=Hack\ 12` (note the `\` to escape the space)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroll up
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroll down.

This works for most terminals.

Answer (score 2):

I use Vim in Xfce4 Terminal. I assigned this script to the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> which are the usage `script-name --in` and `script-name --out` respectively.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if Xfce4 Terminal is running. If it is not, exit.
status=$(pgrep xfce4-terminal)    
if [ -z "$status" ]; then
    notify-send "No Xfce4 Terminal session is open."
    exit 1
fi

# 1. Get the full line. 2. Get the entire line minus font size. 3. Get only font size. 
line=$(grep "FontName" ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc)
font_name=$(echo "$line" | sed s/'\w*$'//)
font_size=$(echo "$line" | grep -oE '[^ ]+$')

# Increase or decrease font size. You might want to change this to increase and decrease by two.
if [ "$1" = "--in" ]; then
    new_size=$((font_size + 1))
elif [ "$1" = "--out" ]; then
    new_size=$((font_size - 1))
else
    notify-send "Argument options: --in --out"
    exit 1
fi

# Replace the line with the new font size.
action='s/'$font_name$font_size'/'$font_name$new_size'/'
sed -i "$action" ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc

# Show only one notification at a time.
notify_status=$(pgrep xfce4-notifyd)
if [ -n "$notify_status" ]; then
    pkill xfce4-notifyd
fi    

# Show the new current font being used.
notify-send -t 200 "$new_size pt font"
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried `:set guifont=*`
This brought up available fonts and sizes to select from

I found this info with `:help guifont`

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will change the gvim font size using the same keys as you use in a browser and you can use the mousewheel as well.

Works on Linux and Windows.

[image: resizing gvim]

https://github.com/eggbean/resize-font.gvim